Conditional probability we return one more time given that we have returned $k-1$ time
I am reading Essentials of Stochastic Processes by Durrett.
I am stopping at time of the $k$th return. I can understand in intuition why the conditional probability we return one more time given that we have returned $k-1$ times is $\rho_{yy} = \mathbb{P}(T_y < \infty | X_0 = y)$. But I have some difficulty in writing it rigorously. They say we use Strong Markov Property.
My attempt is we have known that $T^k_y$ is a stopping time. So let $T = T^k_y$, for $n > k-1$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X_T = y | X_{T-1} = y, T = n) = \mathbb{P}(T_y < \infty | X_0 = y) = \rho_{yy}.$$
But the problem is how can we derive the first equality.
